# RestSharp: Saving the expires_in and using it to determine whether to refresh token

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, restsharp

I'm creating an MVC Web Page which makes use of RestSharp to authenticate and give back a token.

When a token is requested, a successful response brings back the following content:

```
 HTTP/1.1 200 OK
 Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
 Cache-Control: no-store
 Pragma: no-cache

 {
   "access_token":"2YotnFZFEjr1zCsicMWpAA",
   "token_type":"example",
   "expires_in":3600,
   "refresh_token":"tGzv3JOkF0XG5Qx2TlKWIA",
   "example_parameter":"example_value"
 }
```

How can the 'expires_in' content be stored in C# so that it can be used every time the call and check is made? As, there needs to be a refresh_token call only when the time runs out

I know it can be stored in a model class but then would this always be saved as the set value? I believe the values reset every time this class is called?

```
public class TokenResponse
{
    public string access_token { get; set; }
    public string token_type { get; set; }
    public string expires_in { get; set; }
    public string refresh_token { get; set; }
    public string example_parameter { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear

Comment: I'm wondering how I can save the 'expires_in'  component so that it can be used every time you make a call.

Comment: A common way to do this is to store the token in a (encrypted) cookie or local storage on the client which sends the data with every call to the server.

Comment: `How can the 'expires_in' content be stored in C#` In a database is a common solution.

Comment: What exactly are you using RestSharp for? Are you calling an external resource?